# GImP Plugin: unable to access GimpDrawble or Gimpimage resolution

Tags: plugins, development, gimp

m trying to get image resulotion in a plugin I m writing. But when I call resolution function the plugin crashes saying image does not exist..... But I can access the drawble , plz tell if there us any way to get resolution throuh GimpDrawable

Answer (score 0):

There is gimp-drawable-get-image

http://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/libgimp/libgimp-gimpdrawable.html#gimp-drawable-get-image

That's not really a question for Ask Ubuntu, though - more likely Stack Overflow.